# Cannot horizontally center two font-awesome icons in container

Tags: html, css

I've made some research here and tried all i can but those icons don't want to be centered. Don't hurt yourself with those &nbsp, margin doesn't seems to work..

```css
    [class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
    }
    td a {
      text-align:center;
    }
    .fa-phone {
        color: #86b545;
    }
    .fa-map-signs{
        color: #86b545;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a class="fa fa-phone fa-3x" href="tel:+33500000000"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a class="fa fa-map-signs fa-3x" href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Acttif+Littoral/@47.2957248,-2.2068371,15z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x358670f7109ad0d7?ved=2ahUKEwjMl8zni8rgAhULAWMBHftSDJIQ_BIwCnoECAYQCA"></a> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"]` matches not your icon classes.

Comment: Well i've tried to .fa-phone .fa-map-signs {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

But it doesn't work too..

Comment: horizontally or vertically?

Comment: Horizontally :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best not to use a table layout for this.

```
<div class="icon-layout">
    <a class="fa fa-phone fa-3x" href="tel:+33500000000"></a>
    <a class="fa fa-map-signs fa-3x" href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Acttif+Littoral/@47.2957248,-2.2068371,15z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x358670f7109ad0d7?ved=2ahUKEwjMl8zni8rgAhULAWMBHftSDJIQ_BIwCnoECAYQCA"></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.icon-layout {
  vertical-align: middle;
  // if you want icons centered horizontally
  text-align: center
}
.icon-layout a {
  display: inline-block;
}
.icon-layout a:last-child {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Give that ago

Comment: Hi mark, thanks for you answer. It didn't worked since i have an error for "center" :(

Comment: Because it should be `vertical-align: middle`

Comment: Now i don't have the error but my icons are still stuck on the left :( https://www.acttif-interim.com/agences-m/

Comment: @Vinnie you left my comment in there just remove `// if you want icons centered horizontally` & it will work

Comment: @Vinnie awesome, can you just give me answer a tick if it worked?

Comment: Sure, just one more thing... :p do you know how i can make some space between these icons ?

Comment: @Mark you're a legend !

Answer (score 1):

Reformatting markup for readability & adding a new class `center` to `td`

```
<td class="center">
          <a class="fa fa-phone fa-3x" href="tel:+33500000000" />
          <a
            class="fa fa-map-signs fa-3x"
            href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Acttif+Littoral/@47.2957248,-2.2068371,15z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x358670f7109ad0d7?ved=2ahUKEwjMl8zni8rgAhULAWMBHftSDJIQ_BIwCnoECAYQCA"
          />
        </td>
```

You can then do

```
.center {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
}
```